# How to make a listview table be zipped every 4

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, mobile, data-structures

How to make a listview table be zipped every 4.
items instead of 1 white 1 black..
I managed to do however with odd or even numbers here is the code:

```
return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[

                              Container(
                                color: **index.isOdd** 
                                    ? Colors.black12
                                    : Colors.white,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${snapshot.data[index].descricaoRoupa} ",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

i wish i could instead use index.odd to use an index * 4 something like that
white
white
white
white
black
black
black
black
white
white
white
white
black
black
black
black
white
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use the MOD function. index % 8 = 0-7

```
if (index % 8 < 4 ) // 0-3
{
  //first 4
}
else // 4-7
{
  // second 4
}
```

in your code do this:

```
Container( 
  color: index % 8 < 4 ? Colors.black12 : Colors.white,
  // ...
}
```